# how to use 'else if' in my jQuery properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function with 'click' event. After 'click' is being trigerred I need a conditional statement to do some things based on what button has been clicked. I put some code to make it clearer:

The ul and The a:

```
<ul>
<li class="menu first"><a href="link/to/somwhere"></a></li>
<li class="menu second"><a href="link/to/somwhere"></a></li>
<li class="menu third"><a href="link/to/somwhere"></a></li>
<li class="menu fourth"><a href="link/to/somwhere"></a></li>
</ul>
<a class="logo" href="link/to/somwhere"></a>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('.menu, .logo').on('click','a',function(e){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
        if ($('.first a').data('clicked')) { 
        // do things reserved only for .first button
        }
        else if ($('.logo a').data('clicked')) { 
        // do things reserve only for .logo link
        }
        else { 
        // do things reserved for every other buttons 
        }
        goTo(href);
});

function goTo(href) {
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        success: function(data) {
          // some code
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is, when I click on a menu button, it just doesn't work. I want it to do something, depedning on which button has been clicked. When I click on '.first' it works, when I click on '.logo' it also works but the third one, 'else', is being omitted.

Comment: You're missing the `(` after `if`.

Comment: jQuery is a library written in JavaScript. 'else if' and all the other conditional statements will work with it.

Comment: The code you posted is not syntactically correct. A much simpler way to do what your doing is to use `if ($(this).is('.logo'))` or `if ($(this).is('.menu a'))`.

Comment: No-one is saying that else if is not valid in jQuery.  jQuery is alibrary buult on javascript - it adds an extra set of functions to javascript.  else if is basic javascript, so it can be used in conjunction with jQuery but it does not require jQuery and is not any different when using jQuery then when using plain javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That whole deal with the `.data()` seems like a round-about way to do this:

```
if ($(this).is('.menu a')) {
  // menu button, or ".first a" for just the first one, etc
}
else if ($(this).is('.logo')) {
  // the logo button
}
```

Comment: I needed to put insert `a` after `logo` and it works properly, thank you for help! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
else if ($('.logo a').data('clicked')) {
```

And close your original .on() event:

```
$('.menu, .logo').on('click','a',function(e){
  //DO STUFF

}); //Closing curly brace and paren
```

Comment: Originally it's closed, I just forgot to put it in an example above, but thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do things based on which was clicked using the data element then you are stporing up trouble.  You are loading pages with ajax without appaently reseting the data - if you click the first then the second then the first could still have data('clicked') true.

Plus the missing bracket as already pointed out.

Suggest instead:

```
$('.menu, .logo').on('click','a',function(e){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ( $(this).hasClass('first') ) { 
        // do things reserved only for .first button
        }
        else if( $(this).hasClass('logo') ) { 
        // do things reserve only for .logo link
        }
        else { 
        // do things reserved for every other buttons 
        }
        goTo(href);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting your code:

Not sure why you are checking `data` when you set it to true before. Makes no sense to me right now and perhaps you want to check if a user has already clicked on it before?

```
// declare outside event as it is not clear from your provided code where this belongs
function goTo(href) {
    $.ajax({ url: href }).done(function(){
        // some code
    });
}

$('.menu, .logo').on('click','a',function(ev){
    var el = $(this), // let's do this once
        hasClicked = el.data('clicked'), // let's do this once
        parent = el.parent(),
        href = el.prop('href'); // use .prop() when dealing with actual properties

    ev.preventDefault(); // prevent the link from it's intentional behaviour

    // why mess with data here? Do it after you've done whatever it is you have to do or it doesn't makes sense you're gonna check it?
    //el.data('clicked', true);

    // use !hasClicked to reverse the condition(s)
    if (parent.hasClass('first') && hasClicked) {
        // do things reserved only for .first button
    } else if (parent.hasClass('.logo') && hasClicked) { 
        // do things reserve only for .logo link
    } else { 
        // do things reserved for every other buttons 
    }

    // wild guess this belongs here
    el.data('clicked', true);

    goTo(href);

});
```